# jQuery update/ place text

Tags: jquery, position

I have the following, which works fine:

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qbh2B/1/

**jQuery**

```
(function($){
        $.fn.textareaCounter = function(options) {
            // setting the defaults
            // $("textarea").textareaCounter({ limit: 100 });
            var defaults = {
                limit: 100
            };  
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            // and the plugin begins
            return this.each(function() {
                var obj, text, wordcount, limited;

                obj = $(this);
                obj.after('<span style="font-size: 12pt; clear: both; margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 3px; display: block;" class="counter-text">Max. '+options.limit+' words</span>');

                obj.keyup(function() {
                    text = obj.val();
                    if(text === "") {
                        wordcount = 0;
                    } else {
                        wordcount = $.trim(text).split(" ").length;
                    }
                    if(wordcount > options.limit) {
                        $(this).next().html('<span style="color: #DD0000;">0 words left</span>');
                        limited = $.trim(text).split(" ", options.limit);
                        limited = limited.join(" ");
                        $(this).val(limited);
                    } else {
                        $(this).next().html((options.limit - wordcount)+' words left');
                    } 
                });
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);

$("textarea").each(function() {
    $(this).textareaCounter();
});
```

**HTML**

```
Question 100 <textarea class="scanwid" name="q100" id="q100" rows="1" ></textarea>
Question 101 <textarea class="scanwid" name="q101" id="q101" rows="1" ></textarea>
Question 102 <textarea class="scanwid" name="q102" id="q102" rows="1" ></textarea>
```

However, all I would like to do is position the text `Max. 100 words` after the the text `Question 100`.

Cannot work out how to achieve this - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbh2B/2/)

Just change the `after` to `before` and remove the `display:block` css let the span will not change line.

Comment: Interestingly, that stops the Count from counting down.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/j68Sb/1/

Add a `display:inline` and wrap every question block into its own `div`

BTW: It's not counting down for me, it gets stuck at "99 words"

Comment: What is odd, is that by doing that it stops the count down.